# how to get Heap size of a program

Tags: c++, c, linux

How to find heap memory size of a c++ program under linux platform ?I need heap memory space before the usage of new or malloc  and also after that.can anyone help?

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

     //here need heap memory space
     unsigned char* I2C_Read_Data= new unsigned char[250];
     //get heap memory space After the usage of new 
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: new and malloc don't use the same region...

Comment: @UmNyobe: That's odd, since usually `new` calls `::operator new()`, which in turn is usually implemented via `malloc()`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350819/c-free-store-vs-heap

Comment: let me correct this : new and malloc don't **necessarily** use the same region...

Comment: I don't know,but I hear that the free store and heap can be used interchangeably .Anyway can you please suggest a function for finding dynamic memory space of a c program before and after the allocation and de_allocation?

Answer (score 6):

You can also add heap tracking to your own programs by overloading the `new` and `delete` operators. In [a game engine](https://github.com/CYBORUS/cyborus-game-engine) I am working on, I have all memory allocation going through special functions, which attach each allocation to a particular heap tracker object. This way, at any given moment, I can pull up a report and see how much memory is being taken up by entities, actors, Lua scripts, etc.

It's not as thorough as using an external profiler (particularly when outside libraries handle their own memory management), but it is very nice for seeing exactly what memory you were responsible for.

[image: sample of my memory tables]

Answer (score 5):

Use valgrind's heap profiler: [Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)

Comment: I am using 'arm-linux' platform....How valgrind's can be used with this platform?any idea?

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can read `/proc/[pid]/statm` to get memory usage information.

> Provides information about memory usage, measured in pages.  The
>                 columns are:
>
> ```
>               size       total program size
>                          (same as VmSize in /proc/[pid]/status)
>               resident   resident set size
>                          (same as VmRSS in /proc/[pid]/status)
>               share      shared pages (from shared mappings)
>               text       text (code)
>               lib        library (unused in Linux 2.6)
>               data       data + stack
>               dt         dirty pages (unused in Linux 2.6)
> ```

See the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more details.

Answer by Adam Zalcman to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367001/how-to-check-heap-size-for-a-process-on-linux-machineubuntu) describes some interesting details of the heap allocation

Comment: The units are pages. You can use getconf PAGE_SIZE to know how big a page is in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit) function call and pass the `RLIMIT_DATA` for the resource. That should give you the size of the data segment for your program.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ,can you please give me a sample code ?

Comment: A simple search would have yielded links like this - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/getrlimit-is-setting-soft-and-hard-limits-to-1-why-160165/

Comment: Hi,
In this it shows the memory space,but not changed after space is allocated.

Comment: getrlimit returns the limit for heap, not what is currently used

Answer (score 0):

Apart from external inspection, you can also instrument your implementation of malloc to let you inspect those statistics. `jemalloc` and `tcmalloc` are implementations that, on top of performing better for multithreaded code that typical libc implementations, add some utility functions of that sort.

To dig deeper, you should learn a bit more how heap allocation works. Ultimately, the OS is the one assigning memory to processes as they ask for it, however requests to the OS (syscalls) are slower than regular calls, so in general an implementation of `malloc` will request large chunks to the OS (4KB or 8KB blocks are common) and the subdivise them to serve them to its callers.

You need to identify whether you are interested in the total memory consumed by the process (which includes the code itself), the memory the process requested from the OS within a particular procedure call, the memory actually in use by the `malloc` implementation (which adds its own book-keeping overhead, however small) or the memory *you* requested.

Also, fragmentation can be a pain for the latter two, and may somewhat blurs the differences between really used and assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "mallinfo" and "malloc_info".   They might work.   mallinfo has issues when you allocate more than 2GB.   malloc_info is o/s specific and notably very weird.   I agree - very often it's nice to do this stuff without 3rd party tools.