# How to find the heap memory usage of a process?

Tags: linux, memory, heap-memory

I would like to find out the size of heap memory being used by a process. I used the following command, which gives *some* information about heap memory, but it is unclear if it produces the result I am after.

```
\$ fgrep '[heap]' maps

01538000-01ce2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out valgrind, specifically the tool called [massif](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#massif).

It gives you a way to interrogate the heap usage, and pretty much everything else memory-related. Be warned it will make your program run really slow though.

PS: Possible duplicate of [how to get Heap size of a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748792/how-to-get-heap-size-of-a-program) ?