# linux how to check actual heap size

Tags: linux, size, heap-memory

We see two options:

1. C code to print
   `extern char end;
   printf(" Current heap size: %10p", sbrk(0) - (void *)&end);`
2. [heap] segment in /proc/***/maps [the post to check maps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73627/how-to-find-heap-memory-of-a-running-process)

In our case, 1 gives 0xb9dc00, while 2 "00d50000-00d71000" i.e. 0x21000. Is the option 1 real? or what is option 2 results then?

Thanks,

Comment: You should read over the formatting guide when posting on StackOverflow. This question is unlikely to get as much attention as it otherwise would due to the poor formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check heap size for a process on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367001/how-to-check-heap-size-for-a-process-on-linux)