# Xmx settings in elasticbean stalk through environment properties

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had been trying to up the memory of my elastic beanstalk console using JAVA_OPTS in environment settings with values -Xms1G -Xmx3G. Attached is the image on how I have changed the settings.
AFter applying the changes and restarting the vm, I do not see the changes refelcted on the server.

This is how I am verifying

sudo jmap -heap

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 100
   MaxHeapSize              = 1035993088 (988.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 21495808 (20.5MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 344981504 (329.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 43515904 (41.5MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 192413696 (183.5MB)
   used     = 18710296 (17.843528747558594MB)
   free     = 173703400 (165.6564712524414MB)
   9.723993867879342% used
From Space:
   capacity = 26738688 (25.5MB)
   used     = 22166296 (21.139427185058594MB)
   free     = 4572392 (4.360572814941406MB)
   82.89971445121017% used
To Space:
   capacity = 27262976 (26.0MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 27262976 (26.0MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 691011584 (659.0MB)
   used     = 571332904 (544.8655166625977MB)
   free     = 119678680 (114.13448333740234MB)
```

[image: leastic bean stalk]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heap settings cannot be set through environment properties. You have to give this via Procfile. The procfile has tobe bundled when uplaoding.
I had to created a zip file that had war and Procfile.
Proc file contents

```
web: java -jar -Xms1G -Xmx3G application.war
```

How to test this works?
Find the process id of your webapp/java process from top.
Use jmap heap - to get the heap allocation. I tested this on AWS-Ec2 for elastic beanstalk

[image]